# select input fields based on text with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

With selenium and python I would like to write text to input fields which are selected by text shown in front of. I don't wand to use XPATH based on source code of a webpage because the solution should be useable on all respective webpages with input fields, offered by different service providers. I would just work on the basis of the text which is visible in the brower.

Based on the name the respective ID Number has to be inserted manually. This hat to be automated.

| Name | ID Number |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | inputfield1 |
| text2 | inputfield2 |

I selected the respective element with

```
<kbd>element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*/text()[.="text2"]
```

But I cannot write to the following inputfield2, even selecting it with

```
element2 = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "input").to_right_of(element))
```

trying to write:

```
element2.send_keys("inputtext")
```

Where is my error?

The solution should be applicable to all simlar websites with input tables like:

| Name | Country | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text1 | somemoretextA | inputfield1 |
| text2 | somemoretextB | inputfield2 |

or another website:

| Name | Language | Country | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text1 | moretextA | somemoretextA | inputfield1 |
| text2 | moretextB | somemoretextB | inputfield2 |

Based on text ("text2") I would like to write into the input field of the same row ("ID Number").

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To narrow my question: I can write to the input field, if I now  
its name:  

```element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='title']")
element.send_keys("ddd")
element.get_attribute("value")```  
  
But I don't know the name of the field in general. So I would like to refer to it with:
```element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Titel')]")
element2 = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.XPATH, "//input").to_right_of(element))```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'magic trick' to do what you want to do (if I understood correctly). The proper way of solving problems like "different providers have different page layout" is using page objects.

Let's say provider 'A' has `<input name="country">` and provider 'B' has `<input name="origin">`. If you have a page object for provider 'A' and 'B' with their proper implementation then you can just call method with works for both.

High level implementation for for something like this:

pages.py

```
class FillCountryBase(BasePage):

    def get_country_field(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Implement this on provider level!')

    def fill_country(self, data):
        element = self.get_country_field()
        element.send_keys(data)
```

project_a_pages.py

```
class FillCountry(FillCountryBase):

    def get_country_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_name('country')
```

project_b_pages.py

```
class FillCountry(FillCountryBase):

    def get_country_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_name('origin')
```

Now in your code all you need to know which source should be used. You can do this for project 'A': `page_ojbect_collection = project_a_pages` and this for project 'B': `page_ojbect_collection = project_b_pages` in a setup phase, like `unittest.TestCase.setUp`.

And then a common implementation may be something like this:

```
country_filler_page = page_ojbect_collection.FillCountry
country_filler_page.fill_country('my test data')
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much, but I want to work with the text visible to the user, not on the source code or document structure. I unterstand that your approach is much more stable but usability counts. How can I work with the input box next or a text field just right to a unique text on a webpage?